# Problem While Upgrading Modem Manager Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, usb-modem

I am having a problem with Mobile broadband, it frequently disconnects about every 2-3 seconds. There was not any updates available in the synaptic package manager.

I downloaded the source from this link (ver. 0.7.)
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/ModemManager/

And then tried to install according to instructions given, configure Make, the install was done, but modem manager is not working.

When I type command modem-manager in the terminal, it asks to install modem-manager.

Is there anything I am missing. I don't know what to do next. Can somebody provide me the `.deb` package for 12.04.3 LTS x64 version, so that I can install the same with just one click, with GDEBI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to install Modem manager from sources which are difficult to install. Modem Manager is in Ubuntu Repository . Run this command to install :

```
sudo apt-get install modemmanager modem-manager-gui
```

If you need to upgrade Modem Manager, run:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install modemmanager
```

Or you can Download the latest version from [www.updatesubuntu.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/main/base/modemmanager) and install the `.deb` file.

```
sudo dpkg -i [FILENAME]
```

** Or right click on the file and select `Open with Software Center` or `Open with Gdebi Package Installer`.

Comment: But ubuntu version is 0.5 and it is not working for me. While latest version is 0.7, that's why

Comment: O.5 is the one available for 12.04. You can download the latest version from [www.updatesubuntu.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/main/base/modemmanager). Doesnt know weather it works in ubuntu 12.04. Try.

Comment: I already have the 0.5 version installed, this is not working well for me.

Comment: Sorry, There was a problem in link. I edited it now. Go to the link again.